# Not understandable RemoteAccessException while sending email

Tags: java, ios, spring, email

Suddenly, on the production server while sending email I am getting the following Exception stack stack.  I cannot reproduce this exception on my local working with about the same data. Any idea is appreciated

Exception when sending email, but not an emailException type, e.g.     java.io.IOException RemoteAccessException

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not access HTTP invoker remote service at [http://10.0.1.21:8020/cmserver/emailService.remote]; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: com.braintreegateway.BraintreeGateway
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:212)
    at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy120.composeAndSendSdiEmail(Unknown Source)
    at com.destinations.service.impl.SdiOrderServiceImpl.processVoidOrRefundOrderPayment(SdiOrderServiceImpl.java:238)
```

Comment: Are you connecting to same email server successfully from local? Are you getting this error in production consistently or one off?

Comment: No, on local I have the different server.  I do not get this error in production consistently.  However, a lot of other similar emails going through composeAndSendSdiEmail but only the ones from processVoidOrRefundOrderPayment result in this exception stack

Comment: Looking at the exception `java.io.NotSerializableException`, makes me think that the class or one/more of its field(s) does not implement Serializable.